# applescript help naming .plist and removing extention

Tags: applescript, osx-yosemite, info.plist

i am creating an applescript to create a file with property list elements but without the .plist extension!

my issue is if i use a dialog to get the name of the file eg.

```
tell application "SystemUIServer"
display dialog "Enter filename :- " buttons {"Generate file"} default answer "Generate Keyfile"
set fileName to text returned of result
```

and create the file on the desktop like so

```
set text_file to (path to desktop)'s POSIX path & "" & quoted form of fileName & ".NEWextention"
```

finally i add elements to the .plist

```
    tell application "System Events"
    tell (make new property list file with properties {name:text_file})
        make new property list item at end with properties {kind:string, name:"regName", value:"FOO"}
        make new property list item at end with properties {kind:string, name:"regNumber", value:"BAR" as text}
    end tell
end tell
end tell
```

however the file that is created is has '' when quoted from fileName and still has the .plist extention.
    eg input :-   myfile

```
output:- 'myfile'.NEWextention.plist
```

when i want

```
myfile.NEWextention
```

how can i achieve this in applescript?

any help would be greatly appreciated!
many thanks in advance.

```
              below is the fixed code thanks to @McUsr
```

without his help i would have been at the same point for over 6 months of trial and error

```
tell application "SystemUIServer"
display dialog "Enter FileName :- " buttons {"Generate file"} default answer "Generate file"
set FileName to text returned of result


set text_file to (path to desktop folder as text) & FileName & ".plist"
set dateStamp to do shell script "date"

tell application "System Events"
    tell (make new property list file with properties {name:text_file})
        make new property list item at end with properties {kind:string, name:"Name", value:FileName}
        make new property list item at end with properties {kind:string, name:"Date", value:dateStamp}
    end tell

end tell
```

end tell

tell application "Finder"
    set name extension of file text_file to "newExt"
end tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it happen afterwards you are done processing it with System Events, by Finder, (`set name extension of file "Hfs:path:to:file:with:name.ext" to "new-ext"`).

**But** I am not sure if you can expect System Events to regard the file as a property list file, containing property list items afterwards. It is still worth a try though. :)

This is how you must change the name extension, as this don't work with System Events (name extension is a **read only** property).

```
tell application "Finder"
    set mf to (path to desktop folder as text) & "labels.txt"
    set name extension of file mf to "text"
end tell
```

Use the *HFS path* of the file, aka: Macintosh Hd:Users:You:path:file.ext, and not the posix path. And **don't** use `quoted form of` det path.

Comment: thank you for your answer i will try and impliment it now.

also i actually want it to stop thinking its a .plist and start treating it as a text file with a new custom extention.
so if this works it is perfect.

Comment: i meant 

    `tell application "Finder"
 set name extension of file "~:Desktop:" & quoted form of fileName & ".plist" to ".newext"
end tell`

Comment: The tilde won't work with hfsPaths, it may work with System Events though. So try `(path to home folder as text ) & "Desktop:" & fileName` or `(path to desktop folder as text ) & fileName`. Good Luck. :)

Comment: unfortunately i get permissions issues either way :/ is there ways to run it as admin because when i try it wont let me with this function for some reason

here is the log 
`Can’t set «class extn» of file (path to «class desk» as text) & quoted form of fileName & ".plist" to ".newEXT". Access not allowed`

Comment: this is the code i have aded to the bottom but it wont compile :(

`tell application "System Events"
 set name extension of file (path to desktop folder as text ) & quoted form of fileName & ".plist" to ".newEXT" 
end tell`

Comment: Hello, you have to use hfs paths, like below, and quoted form of, doesn't work then.`tell application "Finder"
 set mf to (path to desktop folder as text) & "lab els.txt"
 set name extension of file mf to "txt"
end tell` Name extension, is a read only property with System Events, and read/write with Finder.

Comment: I added some comments to my answer above.

Comment: i tried this 

`tell application "Finder"
 set mf to (path to desktop folder as text) & "" & quoted form of fileName & ".plist"
 set name extension of file mf to "newExt"
end tell`

and it changes the extension just fine however i still get quotes arround the name of the file quoted from filename

eg . `'randomefilename'.newExt`

this is nearly perfect if i can just get rid of those pesky ' ' around the filename. is there a way to escape them?

Comment: Try to remove the `quoted form of`, you really don't need to use that form, unless you are passing something over to a `do shell script`.

Comment: if i do 

`tell application "Finder"
 set mf to (path to desktop folder as text) & fileName & ".plist"
 set name extension of file mf to "newExt" 
end tell`

it gives me the following error when i run the script :-

`Finder got an error: Can’t set file "Macintosh HDD:Users:ME:Desktop:specifiedname.plist" to "newExt".`

it renames the .plist to remove the '' in the name but now will not change the extension again :/ 

output file :- specifiedname.plist

Comment: its done you were right i just hadn't read it propperly

i needed to change